# Assertion failed: !hook.is_linked() в Boost

Tags: c++, boost

Не могу понять из-за чего выскакивает исключение "Assertion failed: !hook.is_linked(), file d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\generic_hook.hpp" . Прошу помощи, так как сам не очень разбираюсь в осях и тем более в библиотеке Boost.

вот основной код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "boost/intrusive/list.hpp"
#include<iostream>
using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass : public list_base_hook<>
{
    int int_;

public:
    list_member_hook<> member_hook_;

    MyClass(int i = 0) : int_(i) {}
};

void func(list<MyClass>* list) {
    MyClass mc(1);
    list->push_back(mc);
}
int main()
{
    list<MyClass> list;
    func(&list);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся идея intrusive list заключается в том, что список "сцепляет" друг с другом непосредственно предоставленные вами объекты. Список не владеет этими объектами, а лишь ссылается на них. Список никак не может контролировать время жизни этих объектов. Обеспечение того, что время жизни этих объектов будет *не короче* времени жизни самого списка - ваша обязанность. Если вы вдруг уничтожите хотя бы один из объектов, на который в этот момент ссылается такой список, то список разрушится.

Вы поместили в список *локальный* объект `mc`, который сразу же после этого был уничтожен (при выходе из функции). Все. Ваш список "сломался". Об этом вам и говорит данный assertion.